# Faster/better way to compare .NET References' properties?

Tags: .net, assemblies, comparison, properties, reference

I am in the process of upgrading an older component which shares references to custom assemblies of differing versions.

To compare the properties of references from two different projects I have been copying and pasting the property values individually from the two different references to a text file for easier overview and comparison. (If need be i could paste the text into a diff app for a sanity check.) But this is a time-consuming and error-prone process.

Does anyone know of a quick/easy way to get a text representation of all the properties of a given reference in a less error-prone process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This information is included in the manifest of an assembly. This is plain text, contains the name of the reference, the key, and the version.

Use [MSIL Disassembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(VS.80).aspx) to look at the manifest of an assembly.

Comment: +1 This process will work but comparing the project config xml will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i just realized that i can find all of the project references in the prj file. Each reference looks something like this:

```
<Reference Include="Interop.FOO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   
PublicKeyToken=9d6cef09c63e9262, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\Lib\Interop.FOO.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

All i have to do is find the similar reference in the other project and compare the two in a text editor or diff app.

Comment: Yes, but you will never know what version of the assembly is used when the project is eventually built.

Comment: Good point. The prj file does not actually hold all possible attributes for a referenced assembly.

Comment: Well, set SpecificVersion = True to fix that problem.